# WPF entity Framework load specified data to List when Window is loaded

Tags: wpf, textbox, window, entity, loaded

I want to load the UserName from my table (who match the UserName in Settings.Default) ToList. Please see code below:

```
private void LoadUserData()
    {
        var item = context.Users.FirstOrDefault(w => w.UserName == Properties.Settings.Default.UserName).ToList();
        userList = item;
    }
```

It says: User has no definition for ToList.

how can i solve this? Any idear?

Comment: `Users.FirstOrDefault()` already returns single `User` instance, why do you need to `ToList()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `ToList()` at the end of your statement.

[`ToList` is to create a `List<T>` from `IEnumerable<T>`.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolist?view=netframework-4.7.2)

In case you have more users with the same UserName (hopefully not) you can get a list of those user by:

```
var item = context.Users.Where(w => w.UserName == Properties.Settings.Default.UserName).ToList();
```

Comment: private void LoadUserData()
        {
            var item = context.Users.FirstOrDefault(w => w.UserName == Properties.Settings.Default.UserName);
            UserName = item.UserName.ToString();
        }

Comment: thanks for your answere, it was bring me to the right direction

Comment: @FehrBenjamin If the UserName is of type string, then you do not need to call the ToString() method. The ToString() method is to create a string version of another type. Eg. int myInt = 2; myInt.ToString(); will create a string version ("2") of the integer 2

Comment: Yes you are right. I just removed the .ToString() and its still working fine. I guess, I have to buy one book and learn somethings more about WPF and MVVM. ; ) Seems like Google and YouTube are not enough